# Reconciling epochal time with OO - is it possible?

Tags: java, oop, frameworks

I just read http://wiki.jvmlangsummit.com/images/a/ab/HickeyJVMSummit2009.pdf
What does he mean by Reconciling epochal time with OO ?

Update:  I don't understand the content of the pdf so my question :)

Comment: briefly explain the content of that pdf.

Comment: An interesting presentation, but the kinds of processing model it advocates — all of which require a clean separation between mutability and values — are very different from those present in many languages (the ones listed on his third slide). This is a very deep kind of incompatibility; it goes right to the very core of the languages' semantics.

Comment: @Lorenzo I don't understand the content of the pdf so my question :)

Answer (score 2):

He means can we introduce Epochal time (where the sequence of events can be guarenteed) into OO programming?

I would point to the Disruptor as an example of how this can be done efficiently and STM as to how this can be done inefficiently. ;)

To be fair its about three years old and I wouldn't have know what to say then.  He was right to question this as an issue and suggest how it might be fixed.  I would say there is a wider understanding of the problem now and possible solutions.

Comment: +1: You most certainly can have OO and epochal programming (I'd point out that Tcl's worked that way for the best part of 15 years — modulo the point that OO is usually added in afterwards there for reasons that don't matter here) but it's _extremely_ different from the semantics of C++, Java, Python, et al. The key is that the state transition view is not the OO view; they're wholly orthogonal conceptual models.

Comment: A bit similar to trying to use functional programming in Java. You can do it, but it doesn't come naturally meaning that while functional programming can be elegant in a language which supports it, it can be relatively ugly in Java.

Comment: @Peter thanks for your clever answer but I'm an idiot so can you be more explicit :)

Comment: Its getting a little off topic, but my point is that when you read functional or STM code its is often much more verbose than you would like esp if the language supported it.  This erodes some of the potential advantages such as clarity or performance.